# How can i get messages using the index in the node.js client

Tags: javascript, client-library

Thank you in advance.

I would like to have a working example using the node.js client of iota, where i give an index to  a function and the function returns to me the messages or the message ids.

I have tried using

`const mes= client.getMessage();`

`const add=await mes.initialAddressIndex(index);`

but give me the error

`mes.initialAddressIndex is not a function`

Also i would like to ask if you know how is the best form to check if a message was sent by a certain trusted source. A minimal example will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the iota.js lib:

https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.js/blob/main/examples/browser/index.html

```
const client = new Iota.SingleNodeClient("https://chrysalis-nodes.iota.org/");
const message = await client.message(messageID);
console.log(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

To fetch a Message by index take a look at:

https://github.com/iota-community/javascript-iota-workshop/blob/main/code/3-fetch-hello.js